# mvc datetime picker setting value from jquery does not bind to model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, jquerydatetimepicker

I have date-time picker that is bound to a datetime property on my view-model.
when I select the date from date-time picker and I post back, it binds the value to the model, but when I try to set the value through jequery, the value is always null.

my model is:

```
 public class viewmodel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public datetime DDate { get; set; }

}
```

and the view code is

```
<div class="col-md-3">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
```

javascript code is

```
$("#DDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

so when I click an option button it sets the date of the datetime picker

```
$(':input[id="rbVatVoluntary"]').click(function () {

    var thDate = $("#DDate");
    thDate.attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    thDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());});
```

When I check the console in the browser, I see that the value is set correctly but when I post the form and check the model property, it is null.

I appreciate any help on this

Comment: You have disabled the control - disabled controls do not post back a value

Comment: `thDate.attr("disabled", 'disabled');` not submit value during POST - use `thDate.attr("readonly", 'readonly');` instead.

Comment: Your `TextBoxFor` is binded on `DDate` whereas your model property name is `Date` ... Is this a typo ?

Comment: yes, actually its a typo

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it worked, thank you very much. I've struggled with this allot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) HTML attribute prevents the input value to be submitted during POST request (treated as null value), as given by this explanation:

> Disabled elements are usually drawn with grayed-out text. If the element is
>   disabled, it does not respond to user actions, it cannot be focused,
>   and the command event will not fire. **In the case of form elements, it
>   will not be submitted.**

If you want to retain the value to be submitted during POST but prevents user to change its content, use HTML [`readonly` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) instead:

```
$(':input[id="rbVatVoluntary"]').click(function () {
    var thDate = $("#Date");
    thDate.attr("readonly", "readonly");
    thDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

Also you need to match the property name to assigned one in helper method:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```